# VSTO - use GetVstoObject to get something else than document?

Tags: vb.net, vsto

I need to do a VSTO add-in for Word in vb.net. I created a custom task pane and want to add a picture and a label to it in runtime. I can use the GetVstoObject method to get the active document and add the label to the body of the document. This works. However, I need to add the label to the task pane. Can I use GetVstoObject to get the custom task pane object? It seems the method accepts only type document.

This is my ThisAddIn class:

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

Private definitionsChecker As DefinitionsCheckerControl
Private taskPane As Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    definitionsChecker = New DefinitionsCheckerControl
    taskPane = Me.CustomTaskPanes.Add(definitionsChecker, "Definitions Checker")
    taskPane.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

End Sub

End Class
```

This is the class holding the custom task pane control:

```
Public Class DefinitionsCheckerControl

' This procedure works
Private Sub addLabelToDoc()
    Dim document As Word.Document
    Dim vstoDocument As Document
    Dim mylabel As System.Windows.Forms.Label

    document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument
    vstoDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(document)
    mylabel = vstoDocument.Controls.AddLabel(document.Paragraphs(30).Range, 30, 12, "label2")
    mylabel.Text = "This is a label."
End Sub

' This procedure I need to modify where I added question marks
Private Sub addLabelToTaskPane()
    Dim document As Word.????
    Dim vstoDocument As ????
    Dim mylabel As System.Windows.Forms.Label

    document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument
    vstoDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(document)
    mylabel = vstoDocument.Controls.AddLabel(????, 30, 12, "label2")
    mylabel.Text = "This is a label."
End Sub

Private Sub btnRunTool_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRunTool.Click
    addLabelToTaskPane()
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GetVstoObject` method is used to "wrap" a native Office object in the extended VSTO object. For Word, this could be the Document, a Range or a ContentControl.

It's not used to work with the Custom Task Pane. You handle a CTP pretty much the same way you would a Windows Form.

I'm going to assume that `definitionsChecker` in your code sample is a UserControl that you're adding to your task pane (`taskPane`). In that case, you add the new control (label) to `definitionsChecker` (the UserControl). Something like this:

```
Dim mylabel As System.Windows.Forms.Label = new System.Windows.Forms.Label()
myLabel.Text = "text in the label"
definitionsChecker.Controls.Add(mylabel)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Thank you for getting me back on the track. There was another problem which broke my code and I was looking for the solution where it wasn't.